# why is javaScript not used in Login page?

Tags: javascript, html, security

I have noticed that many JavaScript heavy applications like gmail,google doc etc(google SSO) and other website do not use javascript to validate their Login form.  General practice is that JS is used as first level of validation, and server side validation as second level
So why don't people not validate Login pages using JavaScript? Is there any specific security risk?

Comment: You can turn JavaScript off in your browser.  There you go.

Comment: Validate username and password for null entries.
If JS is turned off, the application wouldn't even work.

Answer (score 4):

You can validate whether a telephone number looks like a telephone number in Javascript, that's a simple format validation.

You *cannot* validate whether login credentials are valid using Javascript, this *has* to happen on the server. That's because it's not a simple format validation, but the server must check whether information in the database matches the entered data.

The most you could do client-side in Javascript is to validate whether a username looks like a valid username (if you have such restrictions) or whether the password matches your rules for valid passwords (if you have such rules). What that does is weed out definitely invalid values quicker. But especially with login information, you do *not* want to speed up the process. You want the process to be as slow as possible to make it harder for attackers to randomly try usernames and passwords.

Comment: In google SSO Page, null value checks are also done on the server side. This could easily be validated by finding String length before passing it to the server side. But they don't do it.

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of any good reason not to - at least to verify that something was entered for the username/password fields.

Comment: yes true, I would expect the same. But lot of login pages like Facebook, Google don't. Just wondered why.

Answer (score 0):

Simply put, if javascript is turned off, boom there goes your validation. Using a server side language such as php to validate a form is simply the most effective and most secure way of validating a form considering you can't turn them off.

> If someone turns off their JS, they could creat an account without a username, or without a password, all you have to do with php is run isset and this cant happen.

Comment: What is the point of logging in to a javascript heavy application? Yes, general practice is use both client side(JavaScript) and server side(server language) validation. Since programmatic approach(non browser) request don't even process javaScript, Server side validation is a must.